# ImageMagick doesn't change resolution on picture

Tags: php, imagemagick, resolution, dpi

I have a project where I have a hotfolder system in place where I drop a file in a folder and it executes an PHP script that does some magic on the file with ImageMagick.

One of the operations I want to do with ImageMagick is the simple process to change the resolution of a picture.

What I want to do is to get the picture in 72 DPI resolution. This is part of my code:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(72,72);
$im->readimage($xmlConfig->general->input); //Input is TIF 300 DPI
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(72,72);
$im->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,0);
$im->setimageformat($xmlConfig->extension); //added in EDIT
$im->writeimage($xmlConfig->general->output); //Output is also 300 DPI Filename is something.jpg added in EDIT
$im->destroy();
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Because I cannot get this to work. I have tried all combinations available to try to get this correct and also googling this as a maniac and still do not get the result I want.

**Edit:* I noticed when I did some testing that this actually works. But its when I add the part with `setimageformat` to JPEG and set the filename to *something.jpg* that it goes wrong.

The JPEG is always 300 DPI even if I have specified 72 above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that i need to do this to remove any profile attached to the file to be able to do changes to the picture.

```
$im->stripimage();
```

Comment: This was the only way that fixed it for me, after pulling my hair out :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

I did the following:

```
# Create a TIF with density 300 and undefined units
convert -size 1000x1000 -density 300 xc:red input.tif

# Check what got created
identify -verbose input.tif | egrep -i "units|resol"
Resolution: 300x300
Units: Undefined
```

Ran your code, modified as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(72,72);
$im->readimage('input.tif'); //Input is TIF 300 DPI
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(72,72);
$im->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,0);
$im->setimageformat('jpeg');
$im->writeimage("output.jpg");
$im->destroy();
?>
```

Then checked and got this:

```
identify -verbose output.jpg | egrep -i "units|resol"
Resolution: 72x72
Units: PixelsPerInch
```

**Original Answer**

My answer is that your ImageMagick is probably an outdated version and you should update it. I base this on the following:

```
# Create a TIF with density 300 and undefined units
convert -size 1000x1000 -density 300 xc:red input.tif

# Check what got created
identify -verbose input.tif | egrep -i "units|resol"
Resolution: 300x300
Units: Undefined

# Run your script
./go.php

# Check results
identify -verbose output.tif | egrep -i "units|resol"
Resolution: 72x72
Units: PixelsPerInch
```

My version is as follows:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-10-26 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question above, as I noticed that this code actually worked and that it was when i set JPEG as output format and filename as JPG that it became wrong. Could you test this also and see if you get the same results. In that case i need to upgrade to latest version of Imagemagick, because i have 6.8.8 i think

Comment: I think that the problem lies in that my TIF had a profile included where it was stated that the image was in 300 DPI. You would need to test your code on a image that has a profile attached that has a different DPI than your destination DPI. Then if I run stripimage command on the conversion i get the DPI to change otherwise it just uses the resolution from the profile in the original TIFF.

Comment: Ah, yes. I can imagine that.